# Test if a point on a hexagonal lattice falls on a specified superlattice?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, integer-lattices

Based on previous answers ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3327055/284619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3669788/284619), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3669461/284619)) integers $i, j$ produce a hexagonal lattice using

$$x = i + j/2$$
$$y = j \sqrt{3} / 2.$$

From a point $k, l$ I can make a superlattice from integers $I, J$ using

$$i_{sup} = I k + J (-l)$$
$$j_{sup} = I l + J (k+l)$$

and

$$x_{sup} = i_{sup} + j_{sup}/2$$
$$y_{sup} = j_{sup} \sqrt{3} / 2.$$

If I have a point $m, n$ on the lattice, is there a simple test I can apply to find out if it is on the superlattice as well?

Example for $k, l = 3, 1$

[image: hexagonal superlattice] [Python script](https://pastebin.com/Epp8n33X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one's all linear algebra all the time: your two lattices can be considered as transformations of a square lattice, taking integer $(i,j)$ through a linear transformation.

The two lattices coincide at a particular point if the $(i,j)$ for a particular lattice point, passed through the transform of that lattice and then the inverse transform of the other lattice, give integer results.

So in this particular case:

the blue lattice is the transformation of the unit square lattice through

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and the red lattice is the transformation of the unit square lattice through

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{7}{2} & -1 \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 2\sqrt{3} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

To get the test matrix, we find $$B^{-1}A = \frac{\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 3 \\
-1 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}}{15}$$

Now, to discover if a particular point from the blue lattice is also on the red lattice, we simply apply this new matrix to the $(i,j)$ coordinates, and see if the result is in the integers: $(3,1)$ gives $(1,0)$ so is on the red lattice; $(4, -7)$ gives $(\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{5}{3})$ which is not integer so it is not on the red lattice.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer! I'll dig in in the morning after coffee; this is extremely helpful to me because I've been away from math for more decades than I'd like to admit. I was hoping there would be a test that would return let's say zero if on-red-lattice and non-zero if off-red-lattice. If the result is $x, y$ for example I suppose I could apply a test like $|mod(x, 1)| + |mod(y, 1)|$ to see if it is a pair of integers or not.

Comment: well, if you're working in python, `int(x) == x` works to check for integerness.

Comment: If there was a test that involved integer-only math it would be better, mixing floats and ints always runs the risk of roundoff weirdness. Maybe that's better-asked as a next question.

Comment: Well  - use that matrix on top of the fraction and then check for divisibilty by 15

Comment: There was a typo in my third equation, it should read $$i_{sup} = I k + J (-l).$$ Does that change your $B$ to  $$B = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{7}{2} & +1 \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 2\sqrt{3} \\ \end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: [How to best format the question mark that immediately follows an equation in a question sentence?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31283/284619) :-)

Comment: No, I couldn't follow your formula and figured the two matrices by hand.

Comment: I think the +1 in $B$ is what you meant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq3nb.png Both +1 and -1 generate the same points, but +1 is "nicer" somehow.

Comment: The left one is the image as it was when I made the answer.  It looks like that changed too

Comment: ya it was a typo, it wouldn't make sense for $j$ to appear on the right hand side of that equation, and for some reason I'd carried it into the plotting script as well. With that corrected, putting a +1 into $B$ brings everything back into alignment.

Comment: Do you want me to roll it back?

Comment: If $k, l = (3, \ 1)$ and $$F = \begin{pmatrix}
k & -l \\
l & k+l \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ generates the red dots, then
$$F^{-1} = \frac{1}{k^2+l^2+kl}\begin{pmatrix}
k+l & l \\
-l & k \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ applied to $i, j = (13, \ 0)$ should yield $(3, -1)$ and it does. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for helping me through this! 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZm5n.png

Comment: still plugging away at this, but this question is more specific:  [Test to determine if a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices is closest to the origin or not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705547/284619)